# Dynamic rendering with Rails 5 and Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to test that my controller renders the correct status codes via request specs.  This application uses a bit of meta-programming with dynamic class names to render views.  How can I stub the render call below to return the correct status code desired for my spec?

**Rspec Spec Snippet**

```
context 'renders 200' do
  let(:provider_slug) { create(:provider, :active).slug }
  let(:template) { "providers/v1/#{provider_slug}/new" }
  let(:layout) { "providers/v1/#{provider_slug}" }

  let(:provider_double) do
    instance_double(
      ProviderRouter,
      valid?: true,
      form_model: ProviderFormModel
    )
  end

  before do
    allow(ProviderRouter).
      to receive(:new).with(version: 'V1', provider_slug: provider_slug).
      and_return(provider_double)

    allow(described_class).to receive(:render_new_form).and_return(true)

    get route
  end

  it 'true' do
    expect(response.status).to be(200)
  end
end
```

**Controller Snippet**

```
class V1::ProvidersController < ApplicationViewController
  before_action :init_provider, :init_form_types, :validate_provider

  def new
    @provider_form_model = provider_router.form_model.new
    render_new_form
  end

  private

  attr_reader :provider_slug, :provider_path, :provider_router, :provider_model

  def render_new_form
    render template: "providers/v1/#{provider_slug}/new", layout: "providers/v1/#{provider_slug}"
  end
```

**Updated for Answer Below**

```
context 'renders 200' do
  let(:provider_slug) { create(:provider, :active).slug }

  let(:provider_double) do
    instance_double(
      ProviderRouter,
      valid?: true,
      form_model: ProviderFormModel
    )
  end

  before do
    allow(ProviderRouter).
      to receive(:new).with(version: 'V1', provider_slug: provider_slug).
      and_return(provider_double)

    allow(controller).to receive(:provider_slug).and_return(provider_slug)

    allow(controller).to receive(:render).and_call_original

    allow(controller).to receive(:render).
      with(template: "providers/v1/#{provider_slug}/new", layout: "providers/v1/#{provider_slug}") do
      controller.render plain: '200 [OK]'
    end

    get "/v1/providers/#{provider_slug}"
  end

  it 'true' do
    expect(response.status).to be(200)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The formal answer would be that you shouldn't stub it as you would be stubbing behaviour of the object under test.

You should rather provide a `provider_slug` to be used for the test.

Technically, it would be possible to do this:

```
allow(controller) # controller is the instance of the ProvidersController used under the hood
   .to_receive(:render_new_form)
   .and_return("some bogus value")
```

But this would lead to rails trying to render the default template as no rendering has happened yet. It would thus be helpful to actually call the `render` method which can be achived by:

```
# we call the render method in our stub and thus have to be able to call the original
allow(controller)
  .to receive(:render)
  .and_call_original

allow(controller)
   .to_receive(:render) # not render_new_form
   .with(template: anything, layout: anything) do
  controller.render plain: '200 [OK]'
end
```

Comment: Thank you @ulferts, I agree about the slug, but they can be completely dynamic and in the generated version would not exist.  Overall for a functional test, I love where this is going, even it is just a learning example. I updated the question to reflect your second option, but I am still getting and "ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template" error.

Comment: @ChrisHough can you please try to actually use `template: anything, layout: anything` as the value for `with` ( instead of `template: "/v1/providers/#{provider_slug}.new", layout: "providers/v1/#{provider_slug}"`). Using that wildcard will be more resilient to changes. `provider_slug` is the result of the let block in your case.

Comment: I accepted your edit, but it still does not work. Thoughts?

Comment: I send an edit request for your question which fixes an inverted path expectation for the render method. I could reproduce the problem after I set up a similar application locally and ran into the same problem. I am therefore pretty positive that fixing the expectation should fix the error.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting `Missing template providers/v1/rosenbaum/new with` for example @ulferts